# Doxygen not generating documentation for java interfaces

Tags: java, doxygen

I'm trying to use doxygen to create the documentation for java, but I have a small problem...

I get all the classed but doxygen do not create the documentation for the interfaces... can anybody help me?

The doxyfile that I'm using is [here](https://github.com/BeyondAR/beyondar/blob/master/android/doc/doxyfile) and the version that I'm using is the 1.8.6

Thanks!

Comment: Does your INPUT line include the folders that contain the interface files?

Comment: Yep,  they are in the same package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700168/3345366) can help you. Do not insert tag the end of file without empty line.