# Doxygen: Why is it ignoring my last Objective-C interface or protocol?

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I've got a header file that Doxygen lists correctly as one of the files of the project and it will show the source.

The Doxygen output shows that the file is being processed.

However, the protocol being declared in the file is not being documented in the list of classes.

I tried declaring another protocol named Foo immediately before the protocol that's not showing up.  The new protocol is processed correctly.  I added another one named Bar.  It also is processed correctly but still the original protocol is not.  I deleted the original protocol and now Bar is no longer being processed.

Basically, all of the protocols (or interfaces) that I declare are processed but the last one never is.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of my file consisted of

```
@end
```

This is what Doxygen didn't like.  If I added a newline after @end then it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me.  Doxygen was failing to recognise a large number of my ObjC files and this was the reason. Seems 'intolerant' of Doxygen, if not an outright bug.